# Does class#getDeclaredFields() return synthetic fields?

Tags: java

Does the method `class#getDeclaredFields()` return synthetic (compiler-generated) fields?
The Javadoc only says:

> Returns an array of {@code Field} objects reflecting all the fields
> declared by the class or interface represented by this {@code Class}
> object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and
> private fields, but excludes inherited fields.

Comment: I dont know how to generate synthetic fields.

Comment: Create class A, create inner class A$B, getDeclaredFields on A and check if you see the synthetic fields created by the compiler to let A access fields of B. Tip: since you didn't declare them, you shouldn't see them.

Comment: While I can't speak to synthetic fields in `#getDeclared`, I would imagine that `Class#getFields` would return those. Additionally, `Field` has a method `#isSynthetic`, allowing you to check. My understanding was that `#getDeclaredFields` would only return the fields that were written _directly_ within the class you call it on, not anything inherited or generated. Adding on to @MatteoNNZ's comment, make sure the inner class `B` is non-static, and check for synthetic fields on `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it does. Like [@Matteo NNZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111149/matteo-nnz) pointed out: An inner class generates a synthetic field for "this", so:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.class.getDeclaredFields()[0].isSynthetic());
    }

    class B {
    }
}
```

prints `true`.

Comment: Ah wow, I would have said it wasn't returning them. You didn't really declare that field, it was compiled so I would haven't expected it in here.

Comment: Edit your comment and we pretend like this didn't happen :D

Comment: I take my responsibilities :D

Comment: I upvoted as well because 1) it's an obscure thing I didn't know nor expected, 2) the question overall was short, self-contained, and clear. It's nice finding your own answers sometimes, too!